# Return True/False - when to use it over just return

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have searched over internet why i should use return False/True over just return but can not find the answer.

Why would i want to have statement return True/False inseatd of just return ?
Can you please show me an example ?

```
def test(var):
    if var > 5:
        return True
    else:
        return False

test(8)
>>> True
#------------------------

def test(var):
    if var > 5:
        return
    else:
        return

test(8)
>>> None
```

Comment: Erm, you would use it if you wanted your function to return a value of True or False. What do you think your second function is actually doing?

Comment: If you're going to post python code, post it with appropriate indentation. Badly indented python code is nonsense.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question could be answered at face value, but I think the it reveals a huge gap in understanding that simply answering it would not fix. I suggest going to one of many programming tutorials like codecademy.com to learn the fundamentals of programming.

Comment: `def test(var):` can be just `return var > 5`

Comment: Naming your method would make a big difference to callers of them. `test(var)` means nothing to me, `testVarOver5(var)` though. That seems to indicate a yes or no answer, which would translate to returning true or false. Also, your second function makes negative sense, why would you a test conditation and return the same result from both, at that point your method should just be `def test(var): return` and it'd have the same functionality

Comment: Hey, lets be friendly. OP does not knows what a function is. So What? Answer it or leave unanswered. But the question is well asked and fits S.O.

Answer (score 2):

Analogy: A function is a cloneable assistant ready to perform a task, and give you an answer. The task is defined by the *parameters* of the function (the stuff inside the parentheses). Let's rewrite the names to give them semantic meaning (i.e. names which illustrate what we expect).

```
def isXGreaterThanY(.....
```

Here, the name of the task is "is X greater than Y?". If you go up to your cloneable assistant and ask "is X greater than Y?", your assistant will not be able to accomplish what you want unless you tell them what X and Y are.

```
def isXGreaterThanY(x, y):
    .........
```

Now I can start to explain where you may be going wrong. One error at this level of programming is that just because you see something that does almost what one wants on a webpage, one may be tempted to copy it syntactically and try to fiddle around with the syntax and hope it will just work. This will never work. It is not the point of programming.

Some everyday people think that programming is about magic words (not that I am implying you think that) that solve your problem. This is not the case. Rather, programming is (classically) about being able to make automatons (these little assistants) which manipulate information for you. The rote, mechanical manipulation of information is what computers are good at. We want our tasks to be replicable though, so we give them names like "is X greater than Y?", and specify them in what is known, aptly, as *procedures* (a.k.a. functions).

Let's consider what you wrote:

```
def isXGreaterThanY(x, y):
    if x > y:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

A procedure is all about *control flow*. Each part of the procedure is either a *statement* or *expression* (which you can, at this level, consider to be the same thing). A procedure usually has an *answer*: whenever control flow hits a "return ANSWER" statement, the entire procedure stops (the task is finished) and your magical assistant returns to you with the answer on a piece of paper with `ANSWER` written on it. A procedure which returns an answer is known as a 'function', and this is almost always what we want (procedures which do ugly 'side-effects' behind the scenes are usually not what we want).

Below, I illustrate the idea that takes us from syntax (what we write down) to mechanical actions. A procedure is made up of syntactic expressions, and each expression may have subexpressions, etc.

- We have the `if __ then __ else __` statement, which consists of three subexpressions:

  - the query clause of `x > y`, which consists of:

    - the `_ > _` operator acting on:

      - the variable x
      - the variable y
  - the "then" clause of `return True`, which consists of:

    - the `return` statement, returning:

      - the literal boolean value `True`
  - the "else" clause of `return False`, which consists of:

    - the `return` statement, returning:

      - the literal boolean value `False`

This 'syntax tree' is what the computer sees. Now, the programming language associates meaning to these expressions: it knows how to navigate this tree in what is known as "control flow". In particular, in the programming language Python, we know that when we see an if-then-else statement, that first we check the test condition. In this case we look at the test condition and notice it is a naked comparison (we ask the CPU, and it gives either True or False back). If the comparison is true, we will do the "then" clause, which returns; i.e. hands you a slip of paper with the answer `True`. If the comparison was false, we'd do the "else" clause, and hand you a slip of paper with the answer `False`.

In this way, whenever you ask your assistant "is X greater than Y? where X=... and Y=...", your assistant will (in effect) look at the instructions you've specified in the procedure, and interpret them with the assistant's eye being always fixed on one expression at a time (the "control flow" can be thought of as a highlighted or underlined 'active' subexpression, i.e. control flow is the path your assistant's eye takes while looking through the code). In this particular case, your procedure begins with an if-then-else clause, which it interprets as a branching point in the control flow (a fork in the road); it takes the appropriate branch, and in this case, will discover one of the two 'return' statements, and then dutifully give you a slip of paper.

Control flow is determined by the semantics (meaning) behind special control-flow statements, such as if-then-else. Other control flow structures are interpreted differently. `for x in range(7): ...` will pretend x is 1 and execute `...`, pretend x is 2 and execute `...`, etc.

A `while True: ...` will loop forever, performing the `...` over and over again.

A `break` (break out of) means "stop the while loop" or "stop the for loop prematurely".

A `continue` means "skip the rest of the `...` in this while/for loop, but keep on looping".

You can implement your own control flow using the above and your own custom functions, with what is known as recursion (another topic outside this answer's scope).

That is control flow and imperative programming in a nutshell.

---

By the way, it is better form to do this:

```
def isXGreaterThanY(x, y):
    # this is a comment
    # you can insert a print x>y here, or print(x>y) depending on your version of python
    return (x > y)
```

The expression `x > y` evaluates to True/False before it's fed into the if-then-else statement. So, you could just return the expression as the answer. However, by that point, your function is simple enough that you wouldn't write a function answer:

```
#print isXGreaterThanY(1,3)
print (1 > 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

One major problem is that your second function will return `None` either way. Returning a boolean value is a way to have the return value of your function be meaningful/useful elsewhere.

If it returns a value like `True` or `False`, you can in turn use the return value of your function in cases like:

```
if test(8):
    # do something it returns True
else:
    # do something otherwise
```

Otherwise, you function is meaningless because `test()` will return the same thing regardless of input.

I was once told that a function should either "do something" or "return something". Your second example function,   doesn't "do anything", because the `>` comparison has no effect if you are not making some choice based on the results of that comparison. It also doesn't really return anything (at least not anything meaningful) because it will return `None` no matter what - in fact, even if you remove the `return` keyword, it will still just return `None`.

Comment: Thank you for the comment - This what i would like to see -how can be True/False used somewhere else. Maybe it is very noob question but i am just starting out.

Comment: @user6735313 please read a python tutorial on functions, specifically on how to use function values, you can try this link for some info: http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/functions.html#returned-function-values

Comment: @user6735313 glad to help. When I first started out with programming, I had a lot of trouble understanding functions and return values. It seems so simple now that I have had a lot of experience with them, but it was not so long ago that I have forgotten what it feels like to be a noob. In addition to the tutorial linked in the comments, I would recommend Codecademy's tutorial as well: https://www.codecademy.com/learn/python. If you learn better by doing, I think it is very useful.